# Time.now.to_i different on heroku and locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, time, timezone

I have different outputs for `Time.now.to_i`:

- Locally: 1416844833
- Production (heroku): 1416848333

I thought that it ignores timezones, I also tried `Time.now.utc.to_i` and, as expected, it gives the same results for each environment.

So I wonder, what causes this difference and how can I get the same time in both environments?

Comment: The `to_i` value should be UNIX `time_t` format and should be universal time. Maybe you have some time-zone issues? Those are off by 3500s, or about an hour. That is, `Time.now.to_i - Time.now.utc.to_i` should be 0, or occasionally -1 by fluke. Is your UTC time correct? Does `Time.now.utc` produce similar results on both machines in human-readable format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have one hour difference between environments....

```
Time.at(1416844833)
=> 2014-11-24 14:00:33 -0200
Time.at(1416848333)
=> 2014-11-24 14:58:53 -0200
```

However, `Time.now.to_i` always return UTC, so I don't think it is a timezone issue:

```
Time.now
=> 2014-11-24 15:27:08 -0200
Time.now.utc
=> 2014-11-24 17:27:15 UTC
Time.now.to_i
=> 1416850043
Time.at(1416850043)
=> 2014-11-24 15:27:23 -0200
```

I believe your local clock is wrong....

Answer (score 1):

Check your development and production timezones - if the environments are based in a different region the timezones will also be different. To keep them in sync add this in `config/application.rb`

```
config.time_zone = "your_preffered_time_zone"
```